GORM Help w/ Postgres: unsupported data type
I'm trying to read through the CVE List to put all the entries into a central database. When I try to create an entry to this databse, I get an error: 2024/07/02 14:03:13 /x/db.go:68 unsupported data
The required code is here. Replace # in db.go with the correct information for a Postgres server to replicate.
I've double-checked the struct definitions and have used the GORM documentation for many to many and has-many type relationships. The create(object any) method should successfully insert an instance of the struct passed on the Postgres server provided through the other functions.

There is only 5 lines of Code or so in the link, post code here with a minimal reproducable example ;)

@Christoph there should be multiple files in the Repl that work together. Let me know if you can't see them.

Where does wojtek.Create come from?

@Christoph I'll try making the create case-specifc, but I was trying to make it so I could pass in any struct and have GORM create it regardless of type. Thanks for the insight

On which create does excalty it happens on the last one ?

wojtek.Create was not supposed to make it to the repl haha. It's the gorm functionality for record insertion.

So on which create does it happen?

func create(object any) {
    db.Create(&object)
}

This function is causing an error as the GORM record insertion logic can't tell what data type is being created. Directly calling db.Create(&vuln) prevents this and appropriately uses GORM functionality
